# AWS service to validate user input based on amazon LEX slot types

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-lex

I have a complex use case on my project leveraging Amazon LEX.

right now I only need the validation based on the Slot Types: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lex/latest/dg/howitworks-builtins-slots.html

does AWS provide this kind of service/API without directly using the LEX API?

Answer (score 0):

Yes indeed. The power behind Lex is its ability to leverage Lambda functions to perform custom and complex functions; such as input validation, retrieving data from external services and then building dynamic responses.

You can read more about it in the Lex documentation:

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lex/latest/dg/gs2-prepare.html
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lexv2/latest/dg/lambda.html

These guides should get you up to speed pretty quickly.